# How to make inparallel cross browser testing using Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest, ui-testing

I made my tests by Python with Pytest and Selenium. Currently, I am using config JSON so I can change the browser in tests. but I need to make testing in parallel with cross-browser.